# Have files saved on iCloud drive but also accessible to other users of the Mac

Tags: icloud, sharing

I have some files that I wanted backed up to the cloud (iCloud drive), but I also want all users of my mac to be able to access them.

I can put the files in a shared folder, and all users of the mac can access them, but I can't get iCloud drive to sync a shared folder.

I can tell iCloud to sync my documents/desktop folders, and put the files in there, and I can change the file permissions to give other users access to them, but I can't change the permissions on my documents folder to give other users access to it, in order for them to be able to access the files within it.

How can I achieve both at once?

I don't want to use iCloud sharing, because that will mean that each user account has their own (sync'ed) copy of the files. These are large files and it will unnecessarily use up limited HD space having several copies on various user accounts.

I have tried putting an alias to the shared folder on iCloud drive, but it does not even sync the alias folder, let alone its contents.

Using Mac OS Monterey on a 2021 M1 MacBook Pro.

Comment: Just so we are clear (and as an aside to your real question...) iCloud drive is not a **back-up** it is a *sync* system and as such keeps the same things on all your systems (Mac, iOS, etc) synchronized so they can be used anywhere. So delete it on one device it is **gone!**

Comment: @SteveChambers thanks, yes, my terminology is not quite correct but I understand. I use Time Machine and a network drive for backup purposes, but I also want these particularly important files to be on iCloud so that in the event of a disaster (e.g. fire that destroys both the device and the network backup drive) I have not lost them.